# Can I bind an attribute to web component?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

If I have global `@observable var myObservable = 'foo';` I can pass it to web component like this:

```
    <x-component my-attribute="{{myObservable}}"></x-component>
```

and it's passed to `XComponent.myAttribute` before the `WebComponent.created()` lifecycle method. The problem is when I change the `myObservable = 'bar';` the `XComponent.myAttribute` isn't changed.

Is this type of binding possible somehow? Or is the `WebComponent.attributeChanged(...)` the key for this (when it's implemented by the Web UI team)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `bind-` for this.

Give this a try:

```
<x-component bind-my-attribute="myObservable"></x-component>
```

Also, remember to specify `@observable` for `my-attribute`, too.

Comment: That `bind-`-prefix works. Thanks! I didn't find it from the documentation. Only binding for input type HTML element. I'd like to give you +1, but i can't - needs 15 reputations :(.

Comment: @jkorhonen you can press the "Accept answer" button (the tick-mark) below the voting buttons.